# How to grant confluent iam acl for all consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Can you plese share the command to allow READ for a userid for all consumer group?

Below works fine. But I want to grant access for all consumergroup for that username

**./confluent iam acl create --allow --principal User:userName --operation READ --consumer-group groupName --kafka-cluster-id UjOnbv9hAsdAk7Tuk4RX4w**

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept the answer so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to work with ACLs for multiple resources:

1. Use asterisk **'*'** instead of group or topic names. In Confluent [docs examples](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/command-reference/confluent-iam/confluent_iam_acl_create.html#examples) it is used with `--topics` flag, it should work with groups as well.

   ```
   confluent iam acl create --allow --principal User:User1 --operation WRITE 
                            --consumer-group '*' --kafka-cluster-id <kafka-cluster-id>
   ```
2. To select subset of groups or topics, use `--prefix` flag.

   ```
   confluent iam acl create --allow --principal User:User1 --operation WRITE 
                            --consumer-group 'prefixString' --prefix --kafka-cluster-id <kafka-cluster-id>
   ```

Review all the ACLs for the specified cluster that include allow permissions for the user:

```
confluent iam acl list --kafka-cluster-id <kafka-cluster-id> --allow --principal User:Jane
```

Example of how prefixed and asterisk are displayed in the liast of ACLs:

[image: List of ACLs examples with prefix and *]